# Calling ALAssetReprsentation's metadata method several hundred times will fail

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I am writing a tiny iPhone app to retrieve metadata, such as EXIF info, for all photos stored in the iPhone, and ran into a weird issue when calling the Assets Library Framework API. Basically, if I am calling ALAssetReprsentation's metadata method (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/metadata) for several hundred times (even for the same ALAssetReprsentation object), the API will report an error and return null instead of photo's metadata.

Here is the code to reproduce this issue:

```
ALAsset *photo = ... // fetch a photo asset via Assets Library Framework
int i = 0;
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [photo defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *metadata;
while (i<600) {
    i++;
    metadata = [representation metadata];
    NSLog(@"photo %d indexed %@", i, metadata);
}
```

Here is the output for the code above. In the beginning of the output, everything is okay, but after 500+ times, the metadata API will report error like "ImageIO:   CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil".

```
...
2011-12-29 21:46:17.106 MyApp[685:707] photo 578 indexed {
ColorModel = RGB;
DPIHeight = 72;
DPIWidth = 72;
...
}
...
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
2011-12-29 21:46:17.151 MyApp[685:707] photo 579 indexed (null)
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
2011-12-29 21:46:17.177 MyApp[685:707] photo 580 indexed (null)
```

I am testing in an iPhone 3GS with iOS 5.0.1. And I am developing with Xcode 4.2 with ARC (automatical reference counting) enabled. And I can only reproduce this issue when deploying the app to the iPhone 3GS device, but cannot reproduce this issue when using iOS simulator with the same code (at least I don't reproduce this issue after calling the API over 1800 times in iOS simulator).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether it's a memory issue? E.g. check with Instruments and/or use an extra autorelease pool inside the loop.

Comment: I am using ARC, do you have any idea in which case there will be memory issue if ARC is used? I will try to use Instruments to do the profiling soon (I am not familiar with Instruments yet). Thanks.

Comment: ARC has nothing to do with it. You can still run out of memory if you allocate too many autoreleased objects in a tight loop. Try modifying your loop like this: `while (i<600) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        i++;
        metadata = [representation metadata];
        NSLog(@"photo %d indexed %@", i, metadata);
    }
}`

Comment: @OleBegemann Thanks so much for this, and it indeed solves my problem. Could you explain it with some more details as an answer below? I will accept it as the final answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that you are running out of memory. The method `[representation metadata]` returns an autoreleased object and possibly creates more autoreleased objects when it executes. All these instances are added to the autorelease pool, waiting to be finally released (and their memory freed) when the ARP gets the chance to drain itself.

The problem is that this won't happen until your code returns control to the run loop. So for the duration of your loop, at least 600 large dictionaries (and possibly many more objects) end up being allocated and not deallocated. Depending on the size of these objects, memory usage can increase tremendously.

This is true whether you are using ARC or not.

To avoid this issue, try creating a fresh autorelease pool on every iteration of the loop. That way, the ARP gets drained on every iteration:

```
while (i<600) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        i++;
        metadata = [representation metadata];
        NSLog(@"photo %d indexed %@", i, metadata);
    }
}
```

This is not necessarily the best solution from a performance perspective but at least it will tell you whether the problem is memory related.

PS: Your code doesn't make much sense at the moment. Why retrieve the metadata for the *same asset* 600 times in a row?

Comment: This code is not the real code I used in my app but a minimal piece of code to reproduce this issue. In my app, there is an enumerator iterating all photos in the assets library and it will lead to the same issue I present above. And you mentioned that "This is not necessarily the best solution from a performance perspective", could you please let me know what are the other possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereMake sure you retain the ALAssetLibrary until you are finished access related assets. From Apple's docs:

> The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied
>   to the lifetime of the library instance.